# Polymer app cannot download dynamically generated file

Tags: javascript, polymer, download

I am trying to download a dynamically generated file in a Polymer 2.0 application. The download works in a polymer element, but does not work in a polymer app due to, I think, app routing. The Javascript code for downloading is as follows:

```
    _downloadCSV() {
      var bigarray = ['User name, Full name, Age, City, Email\n'];
      var a = window.document.createElement('a');
      a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(bigarray, { type: 'text/csv' }));
      a.download = 'test.csv';

      // Append anchor to body.
      document.body.appendChild(a)
      a.click();

      // Remove anchor from body
      document.body.removeChild(a)
  }
```

The code is used in a Polymer 2.0 element. When served with "polymer serve",
 it works in the element demo page.
However, when the element is used in a Polymer application, the download no longer works. The app-route element redirects to page 404. Is it possible to change the behaviour of app-route so that this sort of URL (a.href = blob:http://127.0.0.1:8081/d14faaa1-a0c7-48f9-b3ba-77492c43a551) is handled by the browser, instead of the app ?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your web server to allow your file to be downloaded from your url.

> By default app-location routes using the pathname portion of the URL.
>   This has broad browser support but it does require cooperation of the
>   backend server.

https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-route#hashes-vs-paths

Comment: Thanks! That would probably the best way, however, may not be easy. I worked out a work-around by disable/enable app-routing.

Answer (score 0):

The solution below is probably an easy work-around:

1. Give the app-location element an ID:

   <app-location id="apploc" route="{{route}}"></app-location>
2. Save the app-location element:

   connectedCallback() {
      super.connectedCallback();
      this.apploc_ele = this.$.apploc;
   }
3. Have a function to turn app-routing on/off:

   enableAppLocation(enable) {
      if (!enable) {
          this.$.apploc.remove();
      } else {
          this.shadowRoot.appendChild(this.apploc_ele);
      }
   }